# Extend inner class using code model

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

How can I extend my generated class from an inner static class?

For instance, I have

```
class Foo {
    static class Bar {
    }
}
```

And I want my generated class to be extended from Bar

```
JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel()
JClass aClass = codeModel.ref("somePckg.Foo$Bar")
JPackage jp = codeModel._package("pckag")
JDefinedClass jc = jp._class("GeneratedClass")
jc._extends(aClass)
codeModel.build(new File("generated/"))
```

What I get is

```
import somePckg.Foo$Bar;
public class GeneratedClass extends Foo$Bar {}
```

But what I want is

```
import somePckg.Foo;
public class GeneratedClass extends Foo.Bar {}
```

**Solution**:

You should pass the class name like this:

```
codeModel.ref("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder")
```

And CodeModel will generate

```
package pckg;

import somePckg.Foo.Bar;

public class GeneratedClass extends Bar {
}
```

Comment: you will probably need to import the bar explicitly or import static Foo.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems here:

1. `package` is a reserved word, use a different package name (For this response I'll use `example`).
2. with JCodeModel you should reference the class using the canonical name "`example.Foo.Bar`"

Also, you could reference the class directly if you make it public:

```
JClass aClass = codeModel.ref(Bar.class);
```

Comment: 1. Sorry, I used "package" just as an example. I use a correct package name in real code. I edited my question. 2. Unfortunately, I can not use direct reference Bar.class because the class name comes as an input and does not exist in my class path.

Answer (score 0):

What version of codemodel are you using - I believe the latest is 2.6 as per below.  I just did a test with comparable code and got the result you were looking for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.codemodel</groupId>
    <artifactId>codemodel</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yep, I'm using 2.6 with no success

Comment: Can you try using a package other than 'package' as I believe this is a reserved word in Java so shouldn't be used as a package name - try MyApp (for the Foo class and the generated package) and see what that does.  Actually I'm surprised you could create the Foo class in package, if you try it in Eclipse it prevents it

Comment: Sorry, I used "package" just as an example. I use a correct package name in real code. I edited my question.